# Where to find webpack config file inside a app created using CRA(create-react-app)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I've a react app created using **create-react-app**. I recently saw some article saying to add few loaders to webpack config file. But I've no idea where to find the **webpack.config.js** file inside a react project.

Really appreciate any ideas or suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Webpack config is not available in CRA. If you want to get one, you have to do an eject (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/), but if you don't need to make eject, or you don't wanna do this, you can use the library which is the wrapper of CRA, for example: CRACO or rewrite